# ASP.NET framework authentication with jwt and openidconnect

Tags: asp.net, .net, okta, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET MVC application (.Net Framework 4.7.2) using openidconnect authentication with okta configured. When the user is not authorised, the app redirects the user to okta for login, and it works fine for web browser.

We have a requirement to allow mobile app to render certain pages within app via web view and they will be passing request header authorization with access token.

After a bit Google search, I found that I can add jwt and openidconnect authentication so will check request header for authorization header if exist we will use jwt else openidconnect.

I tried with .NET Core 2.2 and it works fine, but I'm not sure how can I implement something similar in .net framework.

.NET Core code snippet

```
services.AddAuthentication("DefaultPolicy")
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
            options.Audience = "auth";
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
            options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
            options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                NameClaimType = "name"
            };
        })
        .AddPolicyScheme("DefaultPolicy", "Authorization Bearer or OIDC", o => {
            o.ForwardAuthenticate = "AuthenticateSignInPolicy";
            o.ForwardSignIn = "AuthenticateSignInPolicy";
            o.ForwardChallenge = "ChallengePolicy";
        })
        .AddPolicyScheme("AuthenticateSignInPolicy", "Authorization Bearer or OIDC", options => {
            options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context => {
                var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
                if (authHeader?.StartsWith("Bearer ") == true)
                {
                    return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }
                return CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                    
            };
        })
        .AddPolicyScheme("ChallengePolicy", "Authorization Bearer or OIDC", options => {
            options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context => {
                var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
                if (authHeader?.StartsWith("Bearer ") == true)
                {
                    return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }
                return OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                    
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose here, that you are following the quick start provided by OKTA:
https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/okta-sign-in-page/dotnet/aspnet4.

Inside their guide, they tell you to add a Startup class. You need to replace their "app.UseOktaMVC" by "app.AddJwtBearerAuthentication".

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.AddJwtBearerAuthentication(new OktaWebApiOptions()
        {
            OktaDomain = Constants.GetIssuer,
            AuthorizationServerId = string.Empty,
            Audience = Constants.GetAudience,
        });
    }
}
```

The extension is provided by OKTA. If you want to see how to register it all by yourself, their source code is available on github.
https://github.com/okta/okta-aspnet/blob/master/Okta.AspNet/OktaMiddlewareExtensions.cs